# DESC joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

Is there a way to describe the columns of a joined table in SQL?

If I have just one table, for example A I can do

```
DESC A
```

But how can I show the columns of a joined table? Something like

```
DESC A INNER JOIN B on A.id_a = B.id_b
```

Comment: Three users marked this question as -1 but any of them answered. Please explain me why. Thanks

Comment: seems that your question is unclear  ..as you can see in the close content  try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..anyway DESCribe  .. just for a table  ..

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge for explainning

Comment: I'm not sure why the question received downvotes. It seems like a reasonably clear question. Maybe what's not clear (to the downvoters) is why this functionality would be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESCRIBE` is a synonym for `SHOW COLUMNS`. That only works for tables and views.

To get that to work for a "join" of two tables, if we have sufficient privileges, we could create view object, e.g

```
CREATE VIEW _temp_ AS SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b ON a.id_a = b.id_b
```

and then we could do a `SHOW COLUMNS` from the view:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM _temp_ ;
```

We can get the same result using one of the aliases for `SHOW COLUMNS` ...

```
DESCRIBE _temp_ ;
```

or

```
EXPLAIN _temp_ ;
```

Then we should drop the view:

```
DROP VIEW _temp_ ;
```

---

(It's not entirely clear what problem we are attempting to solve; I only addressed the question that was asked, how to get `DESC` to work for an inner join.)

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thanks so much